# Is there any way to receive API call in API testing tool?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, soapui, web-api-testing

I have used some API testing tools like PostMan, fiddler, and SoapUI etc. I have used these to test API mostly written in ASP. Net WEB API. I have  a requirement to create an application which will be used to invoke API request and receive other API request. I thought about it and i think why i create an application to invoke API request if i already have API testing tool but need to create an application to receive API request and return edited responses. I know we can capture the API request, but is there any way to edit the API request response in any API testing tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a job for [soapUI mocking](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html). You can define the response to a call as either a fixed message; a random sequence of canned responses; based on an XPath or XQuery expression; or you can write your own Groovy script to fully customise the response. I've used mocks to test complex interactions and to test parts of my requests and response.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not exclusively looking for an offline solution, you might want to take a look at [Webhook](https://webhook.site/), which allows you yo create a temporary endpoint that returns whatever you want it to when hit by a request.

On the main page, just click the "Edit" button on the menu bar at the top to specify what you want the response to the requests to be.

Comment: It would helpful but i am looking for a tool for it.

Comment: @umer you should take a look at Karate which has both API testing and API mocking combined: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty